# Custom Hibernate NamingStrategy with singularized foreignkeys of many-to-many's

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, naming-conventions

I'm trying to implement my own Hibernate NamingStrategy based on the ImprovedNamingStrategy. This is quite nice... only the foreign keys of many-to-many relations are ugly.

Example scenario:

```
public class Teacher {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Course> courses;
}

public class Course {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Teacher> teachers;
}
```

With my custom naming stratgy

```
public class MyImprovedNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String foreignKeyColumnName(String propertyName, String propertyEntityName, String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName) {
        String s = super.foreignKeyColumnName(propertyName, propertyEntityName, propertyTableName, referencedColumnName);
        return s.endsWith("_id") ? s : s + "_id";
    }
}
```

this would lead to a table **teachers_courses** with the columns **teachers_id, courses_id**.

What i try to realize is a table named **teacher_course** with the fields **teacher_id, course_id**.
Any suggestions, how to sugularize my pluralized named properties of the entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this would lead to a table **teachers_courses** (...)

Are you sure of this part? AFAIK, the default name of the `JoinTable` is made of *The concatenated names of the two associated primary entity tables (owning side first), separated by an underscore* (e.g. `Teacher_Course`).

> (...) with the columns **teachers_id**, **courses_id**.

For this part, you'll have to implement a *depluralizing* algorithm that takes English spelling into account for:

#### [Regular plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Regular_plurals)

- phases -> phase
- kisses -> kiss (!)
- dishes -> dish (!)
- heroes -> hero
- territories -> territory
- days -> day

#### [Almost regular plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Almost-regular_plurals)

- leaves -> leaf
- knives -> knife

#### [Irregular plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Irregular_plurals)

- sheep -> sheep
- children -> child(!)
- mice -> mouse
- men - > man- women - > woman

Honestly, this doesn't look that easy and will probably require some kind of dictionary if you want to be correct.

I think a better option would be to override the default names using the `JoinColumn` and `JoinTable` annotations.

Comment: Thats quite obvious. :( I'll use the @JoinTable and @JoinColumn Annotation for my @ManyToMany relations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As for the foreign key columns, you could rewrite the `foreignKeyColumnName()` method to use `propertyTableName` instead of `propertyName`.

Following the example in `ImprovedNamingStrategy` you might come up with something like:

```
@Override
public String foreignKeyColumnName(String propertyName, String propertyEntityName, String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName) {
    String header = propertyTableName != null ? propertyTableName : propertyName;
    if (header == null) {
        throw new AssertionFailure("NamingStrategy not properly filled");
    }
    return columnName(header) + "_" + referencedColumnName;
}
```